# Writing a library, what structure?

Tags: javascript

I'm writting a library. Right now, I have everything written in a single .js file that goes like:

```
function doThis() {}
var thisVar = 5;
```

I was not sure if that was right, so I considered:

```
function Lib() {
  this.doThis = function() {}
  this.thisVar = 5;
}

var lib = new Lib();
```

Then, on the main program files, I would have to call everything with "lib.", such as "lib.thisVar" or "lib.doThis();".

Any ideas on which would be better, or are they both acceptable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should just look how other javascript libraries like jQuery oder prototype etc. do it.

Comment: Check out the module pattern: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Comment: Is it ok to do `var lib = new function (){ /*blah blah*/ }`?

Comment: You can use [this](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/) for more inspiration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are acceptable theoretically. But both run the risk of naming collisions with other parts/libraries used in your application.

In the first case, you run the risk of naming collisions for the individual functions, whereas in the latter case, you run the risk of naming collisions for the function you choose for the library wrapper (`Lib`).

The preferred method would be to wrap them up in a separate namespace as shown in this page:

http://frugalcoder.us/post/2010/02/11/js-classes.aspx

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 26):

To avoid cluttering the global namespace, I use a structure like this:

```
var MyLib = {
    vars: {
        var1: 'value1',
        var2: 'value2'
    },
    func1: function () {
        return this.vars.var1;
    },
    func2: function () {
        alert("This is func2");
    }
};

MyLib.func1();
MyLib.func2();
```

You will notice I placed all the variables into their own sub-object, this is done purely for easy reading and development.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Here is another *method* I use

```
var MyLib = (function MyLib() {
    var _privateVars = {
        "someVar": "This value made public by `someMethod`",
        "privateVar": "Can't see this value"
    };

    // Return the constructor
    return function MyLibConstructor() {
        var _this = this; // Cache the `this` keyword

        _this.someMethod = function () {
            // Access a private variable
            return _privateVars.someVar;
        };

        _this.someOtherMethod = function () {
            // Some other functionality
        };
    };
}());

var myLib = new MyLib(); // invoke

console.log( myLib.someMethod() );
```

This structure utilizes [JS Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) and a constructor function, so its easy to keep private variables private.

**EDIT 2:**

In addition, I've also used a different closure setup that does not return a constructor (e.g. `var x = new MyLib();`).

```
(function(window) {
    var _private = {},
        methods = {},
        topic, init;

    methods.set = function(value) {
        // Set the property & value
        _private[topic] = value;
        return this;
    };

    // A simple get method
    methods.get = function(callback) {
        var response = null;

        // Return the value of topic (property) in a callback
        if (!!callback && typeof callback === 'function') {
            if (_private.hasOwnProperty(topic)) {
                response = _private[topic];
            }
            callback.call(this, response);
        }
        return this;
    };

    // Init method setting the topic and returning the methods.
    init = function(_topic) {
        topic = _topic;

        return methods;
    };

    // Exposure when being used in an AMD environment, e.g. RequireJS
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(function() {
            return init;
        });
        return;
    }

    // Exposure when being used with NodeJS
    if ('undefined' !== typeof module && module.exports) {
        module.exports = init;
        return;
    }

    // Last-in-the-line exposure to the window, if it exists
    window.myLib = init;

    // This line either passes the `window` as an argument or
    // an empty Object-literal if `window` is not defined.
}(('undefined' !== typeof window) ? window : {}));
```

And to see it in action:

```
myLib('something').set('made public, outside of the closure by the `get` method');

myLib('something').get(function(a){
  console.log(a);
});
```

Please also take a look at the way I am exposing `myLib`, taking into account where it's being run, and how it's being included.

**EDIT 3 (7/2017):**

As a full stack (w/Node.js) JavaScript engineer, and the advent of Browserify, I fully recommend the use of the Nodejs-style `module` pattern utilizing either Gulp or Grunt as a build system for compiling a multi-file (decoupled, smaller bits of code) into one library.

This model helps encourage a more functional approach, allowing developers to abstract more common functions within a library into separate files, making development a lot easier.

Oh, and use ES6!

```
// file: src/divideIntByFour.js

const divideIntByFour = (int) => {
    return int / 4;
};

module.exports = divideIntByFour;
```

...As a siplified example

Answer (score 11):

Look at the JavaScript Module pattern.

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

You could consider making your library compatible with require.js, which is a framework for doing exactly this kind of thing.

http://requirejs.org

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the latter approach is better as it does not create many global variables ("global scope pollution") but namespaces them on an object.

Yet, there is no need for a constructor (`Lib`), you would instantiate your `lib` only once (following the singleton pattern); and you don't need a prototype. Instead, use a simple object literal:

```
var lib = {
    doThis: function() {
    },
    thisVar: 5
};
```

For private (though static) variables, and better code organisation, also have a look at the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) (or [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)):

```
var lib = (function(){
    var thisVar = 5;
    function doThis() {}
    return { // "export"
        doThat: doThis
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Post is old but maybe my 2 cents may help. I have seen and done this with multiple libraries :

```
nameOfLibrary = function() { //name of library needs to be unique enough not to conflict with anyones code
  nameOfLibrary = {};

  //you can declare variables or functions only visible to this scope anywhere here
  var randomVar = 'testVar';
  function onlyVisibleHere() { /* doSomething */ }

  //if you want functions visible to outside set them like so 
  nameOfLibrary.nameOfFunction = function() {
    //code to run
  }

  //lastly return your library
  return nameOfLibrary;
}
```

Comment: Still a great solution for small libraries and extensions. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

`UMD` is generally what's used.

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global.MyLibrary = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

  // Private implementation here

  let secret = "message";

  // Whatever is returned is what `global.MyLibrary` will be
  return {
     getSecret: () => secret
  };

})));

console.log(MyLibrary.getSecret()); // "message"
console.log(secret); // Uncaught ReferenceError: secret is not defined
```

It's an IIFE that's immediately invoked with 2 arguments: `this` and a function expression, which are the parameters `global` and `factory` respectively. This keeps the scope of your implementation private and prevents naming collisions.

If the script is run in the browser, `this` will be `window`, so window.MyLibrary will be equal to `factory()` which is whatever ends up being returned from the function expression in the second argument. This is the library's API.

Answer (score 0):

The latter is preferable. Particularly when writing libraries, it is important to avoid polluting the global namespace as much as possible. Your code needs to interfere as little as possible with existing code.

Answer (score -1):

The second approach is recommended practice, but that can be improved by creating a new Namespace. The advantage is that you will be able to avoid all name collisions that can occur plus you will have a better control over your code. 
I have created  a namespace called "MyNamespace" and I store my Library class inside that. This way even if there is any other file which has class name "Library", there will be no name collision.

```
(function($){
    $.Library = function(){
        this.memory = {}; 
        this.doSomething  = function() {};
    };

$.Library.prototype = { //these will be common for all the objects 
    commonFunction : function() {

    },
    function2 : function() {

    }
};

})(MyNameSpace);
```

Using the below code you can instantiate new objects for Library class.

```
<script>
var lib = new MyNamespace.Library;
</script>
```